# Highstock From/To Invalid Date Issue

Tags: date, highcharts

I have got an issue in trying to generate a graph which has a "Price" axis, and one for "Volume", similar to that in the [example given](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume) on the Highstock website.  It displays the volume axis just fine, but not the prices.

In trying to determine the cause of the issue, I have disabled the volume, and upon doing so, the "From" and "To" rects at the top right both indicate "Invalid Date", yet they have been on the same format, epoch by millisecond, as the volume.

So here is my setup:

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        alignTicks: false
    },

    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 1
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Price Graph'
    },

    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            text: 'Prices'
        },
        height: 200,
        lineWidth: 2
    }],

    series: [
            seriesOptions
        ]
});
```

And here is the "data" for the seriesOptions:

```
[[1362434092000, 20.3],
[1362434093000, 13.1],
[1362434199000, 7.01],
[1362434200000, 9.4],
[1362434796000, 7.23],
[1362434797000, 22.4],
[1362434798000, 13.1],
[1362434835000, 9.9],
[1362435142000, 9.2],
[1362435399000, 6.4],
[1362435400000, 13.5],
[1362435401000, 24.8],
[1362435453000, 6.4]]
```

**UPDATE**

Not sure if this will be of help, but found on line 292, it looks like it is failing here:

```
this[a+"Input"].value=xa(c.inputEditDateFormat||"%Y-%m-%d",this[a+"Input"].HCTime);
```

The HCTime here is undefined, so on line 20, where this function is defined:

```
xa=function(a,b,c){if(!s(b)||isNaN(b))return"Invalid date";
```

Hope this helps...

**UPDATE 2**

With the information in the variable `seriesOptions`, I tried to bring things to basics, and updated the series to be the following:

```
series : [{
lineWidth : 2,
marker : {
     enabled : true,
     radius : 2
},
shadow : true,
tooltip : {
     valueDecimals : 2
 },
type: 'line',
name : 'Test',
pointInterval : 15 * 1000,
data : [
        [[1362434092000, 20.3],
        [1362434093000, 13.1],
        [1362434199000, 7.01],
        [1362434200000, 9.4],
        [1362434796000, 7.23],
        [1362434797000, 22.4],
        [1362434798000, 13.1],
        [1362434835000, 9.9],
        [1362435142000, 9.2],
        [1362435399000, 6.4],
        [1362435400000, 13.5],
        [1362435401000, 24.8],
        [1362435453000, 6.4]
        ]]
 }]
```

This has a bit of a different outcome, one that I hope can help someone know what the problem is exactly - it also produces an empty graph space, but the "From" and "To" both say "Jan 1, 1970".  An improvement from "Invalid Date", but still, doesn't make sense to me when the [Epoch Converter website](http://www.epochconverter.com/) shows the correct translation of Tuesday, 5 March 2013 8:54:52 AM. -- What does this all mean?

**UPDATE 3**

This question has been up for a little while now, and I've received a hit-and-run -1 score which I'm not sure why I deserve.  So to help explain a little more, I have made the following two screen shots:

- [Graph Image](http://www.logisofttech.com.au/test/Graph.png)
- [JS Breakpoint with values](http://www.logisofttech.com.au/test/Values.png)

I hope this helps... It's driving me insane, and the research I've done suggests only to make sure the epoch timestamp is in Milliseconds.

Will be very, very grateful for help to this riddle - am almost finished this phase of the project, and it's been a long time coming.

Cheers.

Comment: What is wrong with price series ? What kind of chart do you use for price, I mean, line or other type?

Comment: This set of data I used with just a line chart - my app re-organises the data to the [epoch,open,high,low,close] for OHLC, but just trying to make the test as simple as possible - so yes, this was just using a line graph.

Comment: Can the person who gave a -1 score, please tell me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The main issue was that `chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({` was being called twice in the script, before each attempt the contents of the `container` were being removed.  On the first iteration, it had data to work with, the second time, it did not.  Hence, NaN on the data.

Second issue, `seriesOptions` was itself an array, so foolishly I was making the `series:` an array of arrays.

I do have a unusual issue with the slider overlapping the volume axis, but I'll figure that out.